# meaning of but in a phrase of a sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have started book reading habit for improving my English. I have started with the novel **Danny the Champion of the World** by **Roald Dahl** as I have been told that the novel will be easy for me to understand, however I am finding it hard from the chapter 1 itself. Below is the paragraph from chapter 1 and I am not able to understand the use of 'but' in below clause, highlighted in bold. My understanding about **but** is that it is commonly used to indicate contrast or exception but I am not able to correlate contrast or exception in below highlighted clause.

> We lived in an old gipsy caravan behind a filling-station. My father owned
> the filling-station and the caravan and a small field behind, **but that was about all
> he owned in the world**. It was a very small filling-station on a small country road
> surrounded by fields and woody hills.

Please help me to understand it.

Comment: This seems like a pretty standard ["dictionary definition" use of *but*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but): "1a: except for the fact", or maybe preposition "1b: other than".  I think your understanding of *but* might just be too limiting.

Comment: Means the same as "however", if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrast here is based on the idea that on reading the first part of the sentence -- i.e., that the father owned the filling station, and the caravan and land -- we might initially get that impression that the father is a wealthy man. The clause beginning with "but" then corrects that impression. Written out more explicitly you might have:

> My father owned the filling-station and the caravan and a small field behind. Now, that may make one think he was a wealthy man, **BUT** in fact those were about *all* he owned in the world.

Some other examples:

> The most common surname in the world is "Wang", but it is relatively uncommon in the US or Europe.

> The mean personal wealth in the US is just over $0.5M, but about half the population own less than $100K.

> The hobbits ate of the feast until they were stuffed, but Pippin still found room to "fill up the corners".

Comment: Can I get any other sentence having similar use of but ?

Comment: I've added some to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be pretty clear and simple contrast:

1. He owned .... (some things).
2. He did not own anything else.

The two parts are contrasting because one is a positive statement about ownership and the other is a negative statement about ownership.